# Debounce function does not work when directly not bound to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, debouncing

I am trying to use Ben Alman's `debounce` [code](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/). I have the following code but I don't see anything executing at all.

```
onChange() {
        var this_ = this
        if (this.autoRefreshOn) {
            Cowboy.debounce(function(e) {
                console.log("debounce worked");
                this_.doSomethingFunction();
            }, 250);
        }
    }
```

This `onChange()` function is fired from `multiselect` boxes like this:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
<ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
<ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
<ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

When these select boxes are checked they continuously fire `onChange()` but I do not see any executions from the `debounce` function.

All of the examples I found on the web implement a debounce function that is bind to a button press or something like that.

Comment: I really don't understand why you are using jQuery for this instead of Rxjs which is one of the most powerful aspects of Angular.

Comment: I am not well versed with RxJS at this time, I am using `jQuery` very minimally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a debounce directly to your `onChange()` method and call the newly created debounced method directly in your template:

**component.ts**

```
  limitedOnChange = this.debounce(this.onChange, 250);

  onChange(event) { console.log('change detected: ', event) }

  debounce(fn, delay) {
    let timer = null;
    return function () {
      const context = this, args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, delay);
    };
  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="limitedOnChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: does your code just add delays or work the same as Ben Alman's `debounce` ?

Comment: It's a full debounce. Prevents the call from being made more than once ever N ms, where N is the delay.

Comment: Is it possible to change it up a little bit to debounce everything when multiple calls are made? And only allow 1 and only 1 call made to the function to pass through? i am not sure if `debounce` is the right word for this modified behavior.

Comment: More Clarification: For example, if two calls are made within 250ms, both calls should be ignored.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This allows the function to be called once every 250ms. Do you want to only let the function to be called once ever?

Comment: You mean, delay the function for 250ms, and if it's called twice then cancel all calls?

Comment: This is a pretty standard debounce, and throttles the amount of calls that get made to 1 per N ms.

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. The reason I am doing this is there is an automatic update call in my code that constantly checks and unchecks these checkboxes I have and I only want to run the onChange() when a user clicks on the boxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156135/discussion-between-z-bagley-and-summernight).