# Block function calls called by another piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**Scenario:**

I have a situation where a large number of `checkboxes` are bind to a function called `onChange()`.

I also have another function that has the ability to reset/update specific checkboxes at once based on some other parameters in the code. Let's call this function `rapidFire()`

Now, what I would like to do is fire `onChange()` only and only when a user manually clicks on the `checkbox`. If my other code (reset/update) or `rapidFire()` that runs periodically, is making changes to the checkboxes where a series of `onChange()` calls are made, they should all be cancelled.

I have implemented a `debounce` logic to capture all `onChange()` calls made by the `rapidFire()` code, however, by the nature of debouncing, it still lets 1 call execute at the end after a certain milliseconds have elapsed.

What I would like to do is `cancel` all function calls made within a specific millisecond threshold assuming that they were made by the update/reset or `rapidFire()` code. I am also assuming here that if a human clicks a checkbox, it's hard for them to click another one within `250 ms` or a similar timeframe.

Here's my code for debounce that I implemented with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613398/debounce-function-does-not-work-when-directly-not-bound-to-a-button/46613455#46613455) post

```
limitedOnChange = this.debounce(this.onChange, 250);

  onChange(event) { console.log('change detected: ', event) }

  debounce(fn, delay) {
    let timer = null;
    return function () {
      const context = this, args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, delay);
    };
  }
```

On the HTML side:
`<ss-multiselect-dropdown (ngModelChange)="limitedOnChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>`

Rephrasing my question: How do I make changes to this debounce function such that it will cancel all function calls if fired back-to-back and only allow function call made 1 time within a threshold (mimic-ing human interaction)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of binding onChange() function with onchange event of the checkbox bind it with onclick event.

In this way only when the checkbox is clicked the function will be called.

Comment: Interesting!, if my `rapidFire()` code checks and unchecks the checkboxes, the `onClick()` event won't be fired? Is `onClick()` event only fired when a mouse/trackpad is used?

Comment: Yes...onclick event is fired when check box is clicked by input device

Comment: so my problem is that the my `checkboxes` are wrapped inside the `ss-multiselect-dropdown` component and if I change `ngModelChange` to `click`, it binds to the parent dropdown itself and not the checkboxes inside them.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () { doSomething() });` .... this i show I got it done and it works now.